# ¿Cómo resolver: Error Number 1109. Unknow table "master_" in information_schema?

Tags: mysql

Estaba haciendo una tabla de bases de datos y cuando la quise ejecutar me mandó el error 1109. Soy nueva en mysql y no se a que se refiere el error
Adjunto mi query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `information_schema`.`MASTER_` (
  `CANTIDAD` VARCHAR(100) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DESCRIPCION_DEL_PRODUCTO` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CODIGO` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Pon la información de error completa

Comment: ¿Tú quieres crear una tabla en `information_schema`? ¿Por qué? ¿[Sabes cuál es el propósito de `information_schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Dos cosas:
`information_schema` es la base de datos donde se guarda la información sobre todas las demás bases de datos, por ejemplo, los nombres de una base de datos o una tabla, el tipo de datos de las columnas, los privilegios de acceso, etc. Es una base de datos virtual incorporada con el único propósito de proporcionar información sobre el propio sistema de base de datos. El servidor MySQL completa automáticamente las tablas en el esquema de información.

Lo importante que debes recordar acerca de la base de datos information_schema es que puedes consultarla, pero no puedes cambiar su estructura ni modificar sus datos.

Por otro lado UNSIGNED esta reservado solo a valores numéricos no a Varchar.